# Linear Algebra 2 Quick questions regarding my understanding of isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I know the definition of isomorphism but can you provide me two isomorphic subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$ that are not identical, and an example of a set that spans a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ but is not a basis for that subspace?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like $\mathbb R \times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$?

And $\operatorname{Span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)\}=\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times \{0\}$, but that spanning set is not a basis for that subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ since it is not linearly independent.

These examples are trivial.

Comment: well for the first one can  u provide me subspaces that arent identical?

Comment: They aren't identical, they are isomorphic. But you could use any $1$-dimensional subspace, such as $\{(t,t):t\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: is that because is is under r2?

Comment: could u explain how rx {0} is different?

Comment: The point $(1,0)$ is in $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$ but is *not* in $\{0\}\times\mathbb R$. For the example in my comment above, show that the map defined by $(t,t)\mapsto (t,0)$ is an isomorphism between the obvious spaces.

Comment: i thought subspaces were something along the lines of x1{v1}+x2{v2}

Comment: That's a $2$-dimensional subspace, so it's the whole space. This subspace matches your form, since it's $\{x_1(1,1):x_1\in\mathbb R\}$. There is only one vector in any basis of it since it is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: ok so basically anything along the lines of x1{1,1}, x1{2,2} all are isomorphic?

Comment: As long as the two vectors are linearly independent